# how to set href value on all elements with a given ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several anchor tags on a page with the same id of 'hrefCompare'. I need to dynamically set the value of the href attribute on ALL of these a tags.

I am currently trying to do this:

```
$("#hrefCompare").attr("href", "foobar.com");
```

However, this only sets the very first anchor tag with that ID. there's 7 more on this page with the same id of 'hrefCompare'. How can I set all of the href values with that ID?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: You are at failure then... Use unique ids. If url is same for all then use class instead.

Comment: Use classes or something like `data-hrefcompare='true'`

Comment: what's with all the downvoting on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with **IDs** (they are unique), try using the same `css` **class** for all the elements you want *(doesn't matter if this **class** does not exist)*.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hrefCompare">text1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hrefCompare">text2</a>
```

*Please avoid using `#` in `href` attributes (if you care about behaviors). Read this to know why:* [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

**Then:**

For older `jQuery` versions use `.attr(..)` otherwise use `.prop(..)`

```
$('.hrefCompare').prop('href', 'http://www.foobar.com');
```

**Finally:**

**1)** To assign the same `url` to every `href` attribute of an `anchor` element, do the following:

```
$('.hrefCompare').map(function(i, v){ return $(this).prop('href', 'http://www.foobar.com'); });
```

**2)** To assign different `urls` to every `href` attributes of the `anchors` according to their possitions (like an `array` - starting from zero -), do the following:

```
$('.hrefCompare').map(function(i, v){ 
    if(i === 0) url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
    if(i === 1) url = 'http://www.foobar.com';
    return $(this).prop('href', url);
});
```

Using this way...

**first** `anchor`, position **0**: ***(text1 => if clicked => will redirect to `stackoverflow`)***

**second** `anchor`, position **1**: ***(text2 => if clicked => will redirect to `foobar`)***

Answer (score 7):

`id` must be unique, in this case I advice you to use `class`, which should work flawlessly:

```
$(".hrefCompare").attr("href", "foobar.com");

<a href="#" class="hrefCompare">a</b>
<a href="#" class="hrefCompare">b</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ids must be unique in a DOM.  try to use a class name and use jquery each function

```
$('a').each(function(k,v){
  $(v).attr('href','mylink');
});
```